# PDE classification

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

That's a simple question, but I'm confused.

What form must $G$ have for the differential equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=G(x,t,u)$ to be linear? Linear and homogeneous?

For the first question, I thought about $G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u$, but I confused if $G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u+b(x,t)$ is actually the right answer.

For the second question, I thought about $G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u$, because it implies that $u_{tt}-u_{xx}-a(x,t)u=0. $

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could simply say that your classification of the equation 
$$
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=G(x,t,u)\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
is the right one according to the customary lexicon, but your questions since are *non trivial ones*, deserve a comprehensive non trivial answer, which I postpone after the following definition:

**Definition 1**. Let $V_1,V_2$ be two $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces (for the sake of simplicity we can implicitly assume that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$) and $\mathfrak{L}:V_1\to V_2$ a function between them: $\mathfrak{L}$ is said to be *linear* if and only if
$$
\mathfrak{L}(a\mathbf{u}+b\mathbf{v})=a\mathfrak{L}(\mathbf{u})+b\mathfrak{L}(\mathbf{v})\quad \forall \mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V_1\text{ and }\forall a,b\in\mathbb{K}\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Loosely speaking, engineers and physicists say that $\mathfrak{L}$ is linear if and only if it satisfies the *superimposition of the effects*, which is precisely what is stated by equation \eqref{2}. Said that, we can proceed to classify the PDE above and say that

1. Strictly speaking, the right answer to the first question would be $G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u$: this is the only case for which the "weighted sum" (with weights in $\mathbb{K}$) of two solutions to the original equation is again a solution. This point of view is for example the one of Enzo Tonti ([1], p. 1945), who defines as "affine operators" the ones for which $G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u+b(x,t)$, and clearly states that they are nonlinear, implicitly not satisfying \eqref{2}. However, when the operator involved in equation \eqref{1} is linear according to \eqref{2}, except for the presence of a term which does not depend on its unknown solution, it is customary to speak of *linear problem* or *linear equation*, as it is done in linear algebra. In sum, we customarily say that equation \eqref{1} is linear if 
   $$
   G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u+b(x,t)
   $$
2. According to the customary convention explained in the first part of the answer, we say that equation \eqref{1} is *linear homogeneous* if 
   $$
   G(x,t,u)=a(x,t)u
   $$

[1] Enzo Tonti (1984), "[Variational Formulation for Every Nonlinear Problem](http://www.discretephysics.org/DEPOSITO/Nonlinear.pdf)", International Journal of Engineering Science, Vol. 22, No. 11/12, pp. 1343-1371, Zbl 0558.49022.