# Why in this linear nonhomogeneous equation, the superposition of solutions fails?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

When a particle of mass $m$ is acted upon by a force $F_1(t)$, its acceleration is given by Newton's second law as $$\frac{dv_1}{dt}=\frac{F_1(t)}{m}.$$ Similarly, when acted upon by a force $F_2(t)$, its acceleration is given by $$\frac{dv_2}{dt}=\frac{F_2(t)}{m}.$$

These two equations have the formal solutions
$$v_1(t)=v_1(0)+\frac{1}{m}\int_{0}^{t}F_1(t')dt'$$ and
$$v_2(t)=v_2(0)+\frac{1}{m}\int_{0}^{t}F_2(t')dt'$$

When both the forces are present simultaneously, the acceleration is given by
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_1(t)+F_2(t)}{m}$$
which has the solution
$$v(t)=v(0)+\frac{1}{m}\int_{0}^{t}F_1(t')dt'+\frac{1}{m}\int_{0}^{t}F_2(t')dt'$$

Therefore, if $v(0)=v_1(0)+v_2(0)$, $$v(t)=v_1(t)+v_2(t)$$ i.e., the instantaneous velocity when both the forces are present, is equal to the sum of the instantaneous velocities caused by each force acting separately. Let me call this superposition of solutions.

Now, consider the differential equations with forces that depend both on time and linearly on velocity: $$\frac{dv_1}{dt}=\frac{F_1(v_1,t)}{m}, ~~{\rm and}~~ \frac{dv_2}{dt}=\frac{F_2(v_2,t)}{m},$$ and let the condition $v(0)=v_1(0)+v_2(0)$ is met at $t=0$. In this case, the instantaneous velocity $v(t)$ in presence of both the forces is, in general, **not** obtained by adding the instantaneous velocities, $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$, caused by $F_1$ and $F_2$ separately. For example, let $F_1(v_1,t)=-m\gamma v_1(t)$ and $F_2(v_2,t)=F_0\cos\omega t$ where $\gamma,\omega$ are real constants. Clearly, $$v_1(t)=v_1(0)e^{-\gamma t}, v_2(t)=v_2(0)+\frac{F_0}{m}\frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}.$$

But the solution to $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_1(v_1,t)+F_2(v_2,t)}{m}= -\gamma v+\frac{F_0}{m}\cos\omega t$$ is not given by $$v(t)\neq v_1(t)+v_2(t)$$ or $$v(t)\neq v_1(0)e^{-\gamma t}+\frac{F_0}{m}\frac{\sin\omega t}{\omega}+v_2(0).$$

Why in the second case, the superposition of solutions fails? How can we see/argue more clearly that the solution $v(t)$ will **not** be $v(t)=v_1(t)+v_2(t)$?

Comment: The equations are non-linear, so naturally, one does not expect the linear combinations to solve the equations.

Comment: @Angel Why do you say that the equations are nonlinear? It is linear if F1 and F2 depend linearly on v.

Comment: $F$ does not depend linearly on $v,$ in general. It could be the case that it does, but not in general, and the counterexamples you presented demonstrate this.

Comment: @Angel Please note that $dv/dt=-\gamma v+(F_0/m)\cos\omega t$ is linear ODE but nonhomogeneous. So I did not get the point.

Comment: You are talking about the sum of $F_1$ and $F_0,$ not those individually. The sum could depend linearly on $v$ even if the individual forces do not. Also, technically, linear dependence implies homogeneity. $F(v)=a+bv$ is not a linear dependence, unless $a=0.$

Comment: @Angel But by that logic, $dv_1/dt=F_1(t)$ and $dv_2/dt=F_2(t)$ are also not linear. But in those cases, the superposition of solution is the solution when both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are present simultaneously (in the sense I have described in the first few lines). Please look at page 6, eq. 1.20 of https://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/onenew.pdf

Comment: All I am trying to understand is why sometimes for linear nonhomogeneous ODEs superposition (in the sense I have explained) works but sometimes it does not (in the second case).

Comment: It seems to me that you are confused as to what comprises a linear equation. For first-order ordinary differential equations, a linear equation in $v$ is an equation of the form $v'+p(t)v=q(t).$ An equation of the form $v'=f(v,t)$ is not a linear equation, unless $f(v,t)=a(t)+b(t)v.$ But, as mentioned earlier, even if $F$ is linear, $F_1$ and $F_2$ might not be. So that explains why superposition does not work. You need $F_1=a+bv$ and $F_2=c+dv$ for superposition to work.

Comment: Perhaps, in order to understand the observation by @Angel you may ant to have a look at [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935116/pde-classification/2935957#2935957).

Comment: Here the systems $\dot v_1 = F_1(t), \dot v_2 = F_2(t)$ and $\dot v_1 = F_1(v_1,t), \dot v_2 = F_2(v_2,t)$ are equivalents only if $F_1(t) = F_1(v_1,t)$ and $F_2(t) = F_2(v_2,t)$.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with changing variables
$$
v\equiv v_1+v_2 , ~~~~ u= v_1-v_2, $$ and simplifying your equations with them, if you can.

But you simply did it incorrectly:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_1(v_1,t)+F_2(v_2,t)}{m}= -{\gamma\over 2}( v +u)+\frac{F_0}{m}\cos\omega t
   \\  \neq -\gamma v+\frac{F_0}{m}\cos\omega t, \\
\frac{du}{dt}= -{\gamma\over 2}( v +u)-\frac{F_0}{m}\cos\omega t, $$
so the two linear equations do not decouple.

It is no surprise, then, that the correct solution you got does not solve a wrong equation; it solves the correct linear equations written.

Nevertheless, there *is* an obvious way to decouple them. You might, instead, define $z\equiv \ln v_1$, so that
$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=-m\gamma, 
$$
which is of the form of your first example, where the variables *do* decouple, in which case, $z+v_2$ is a fine solution as in your correct starting example.

Takeaway: linearity works just fine, but you must  utilize it correctly.

Comment: Tagging on an additional note for the OP: in order to avoid this type of mistake more generally it helps to bring all terms dependent on $v$ to the left. As I see it this was the critical flaw in the OP’s manipulation of the equations

Comment: @StephenDonovan But changing sides from right to left doesn't change the character of the equation i.e., linear, homogeneous, etc.

Comment: @Solidification Yes, but it shows that the operators on the left-hand sides of the two equations are different